# ReactJs - Child not updating after Parent State changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im new in ReactJS and I'm having problem with the concept of state and re-render of component.

In my parent component, I have this state in constructor:

```
this.state = {
        locale : 'en',
        messages : ENGLISH.messages,
        softwareInfo : {
                        software_name : 'Test Default 1.0',
                        default_dash : 1,
                        color_theme: '#009900'
                       }
    }
```

In the Render, I load a component called DashAppBar passing the softwareInfo:

```
<DashAppBar softwareInfo = { this.state.softwareInfo} />
```

In DashAppBar construct, I read that state as property:

```
this.state = {
       software_settings: props.softwareInfo,
       [...]
}
```

And then I print the software name in the bar with this:

```
const software_name = ( 
            <FormattedMessage 
                id="software_name" 
                defaultMessage="{software_name}"
                values={{software_name:this.state.software_settings.software_name}}
            />
        );
```

This work fine.

Unfortunally, parent component make an AJAX call that change softwareInfo:

```
success: function(result){
        //window.software_settings = $.parseJSON(result);
        //window.software_settings = result;
        var settings = {
                          software_name:result.software_name,
                          default_dash:result.default_dash,
                          color_theme:result.color_theme
                       };
        this.setState({softwareInfo : settings});
}
```

Calling setState should re-render the component but the child value remain the same as original and the new value got from AjaxCall are not displayed.

Where is the error? Change the parent state should update the child.

Thanks!

Comment: Ajax call gets triggered correctly ?

Comment: Unless you are going to mutate that property in the child component, don't put it in `State`. Instead just read it straight from `props`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you're passing the parent's state only in the child's constructor. If the parent updates props you either need to do [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) and update the child state or just use the `software_settings` as prop directly.

For example, in the child component:

```
const software_name = ( 
            <FormattedMessage 
                id="software_name" 
                defaultMessage="{software_name}"
                values={{software_name:this.props.software_settings.software_name}}
            />
        );
```

or with [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ software_settings: nextProps.software_settings});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set a `componentWillReceiveProps` hook on your child component to updated it. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops